# Issue in display data in datagridview cell

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm try to highlight some special words in my string that represented in data-grid-view cell, Now i can highlight every word in my special words list but after make that when represent the data in data-grid-view the data not represented correctly some lines shown after his original location and other shown before his original location.
 
This [image: picture] show the result when i try to make the operation in my question words.

this is my code, can anyone please help me to solve this problem.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            string []specialWords = wordss.ToArray();
            try
            {
                Color ForeColor = ((DataGridView)sender).ForeColor;
                if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                    string content = e.Value.ToString().ToUpper();
                    string[] line = Regex.Split(content, "(" + String.Join("|", specialWords) + ")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;


                    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);

                    SizeF[] size = new SizeF[line.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        size[i] = e.Graphics.MeasureString(line[i], e.CellStyle.Font);
                    }

                    RectangleF rec = new RectangleF(e.CellBounds.Location, new Size(0, 0));
                    using (SolidBrush bnormal = new SolidBrush(ForeColor), bspecial = new SolidBrush(Color.RoyalBlue))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; ++i)
                        {
                            rec = new RectangleF(new PointF(rec.Location.X + rec.Width, rec.Location.Y), new SizeF(size[i].Width, e.CellBounds.Height));
                            if (specialWords.Contains(line[i].ToUpper()))
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(line[i], e.CellStyle.Font, bspecial, rec, sf);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(line[i], e.CellStyle.Font, bnormal, rec, sf);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Why not trying to manipulate the text on the grid's event (OnCreating).

Comment: @OmerBTW not working with my needs to highlight some words.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid`!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: @TaW Sorry for that i will edit my question